Is it possible for selenium to detect specific requests sent to a site in the devtools network tab?
I am using Selenium on python with Chrome and Firefox. I want selenium to wait until a specific request is sent to a site which can be located in the network tab in devtools. e.g. a request with the name of "index-24c3e2ca18.js" and a request URL of "https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/js/index-24c3e2ca18.js"
Could this be done with selenium? If not what can be done to achieve this?
